# integrate native chart display incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I try to integrate smart [native chart](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) which implements by swift to my react native project, but I notice that when I move while displaying messy.

[image]

I provide relevant code below.

### oc side

**CustomChartsManager.m**

```
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import "Demo-Swift.h"


@interface CustomChartsManager: RCTViewManager <ChartViewDelegate>

@property LineChartView *chartView;
@property BalloonMarker *marker;

@end

@implementation CustomChartsManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()


- (UIView *)view
{
  _chartView = [[LineChartView alloc] init];
  _chartView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  _chartView.delegate = self;
  _chartView.descriptionText = @"miao";
  _chartView.noDataText = @"miaomiao~";
  _chartView.noDataTextDescription = @"You need to provide data for the chart.";
  
  _chartView.dragEnabled = YES;
  [_chartView setScaleEnabled:YES];
  _chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = YES;
  _chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;

  ChartLimitLine *llXAxis = [[ChartLimitLine alloc] initWithLimit:10.0 label:@"Index 10"];
  llXAxis.lineWidth = 4.0;
  llXAxis.lineDashLengths = @[@(10.f), @(10.f), @(0.f)];
  llXAxis.labelPosition = ChartLimitLabelPositionRightBottom;
  llXAxis.valueFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f];
  [_chartView.xAxis addLimitLine:llXAxis];
  
  ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _chartView.leftAxis;
  leftAxis.customAxisMax = 220.0;
  leftAxis.customAxisMin = -50.0;
  
  leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = YES;
  leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = YES;
  
  _chartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
  
  [_chartView.viewPortHandler setMaximumScaleY: 2.f];
  [_chartView.viewPortHandler setMaximumScaleX: 2.f];
  
  BalloonMarker *marker = [[BalloonMarker alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:40/255. alpha:0.7] font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0)];
  marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(80.f, 40.f);
  _chartView.marker = marker;
  
  [_chartView animateWithXAxisDuration:2.5 easingOption:ChartEasingOptionEaseInOutQuart];
  
  [self setDataCount:30 range:40];
  
  return _chartView;
}

- (void)setDataCount:(int)count range:(double)range
{
  NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    [xVals addObject:[@(i) stringValue]];
  }
  
  NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    double mult = (range*2 + 1);
    double val = (double) (arc4random_uniform(mult)) + 3;
    [yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:val xIndex:i]];
  }
  
  LineChartDataSet *set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"DataSet 1"];
  
  set1.highlightLineDashLengths = @[@5.f, @2.5f];
  [set1 setColor:UIColor.blueColor];
  [set1 setCircleColor:UIColor.blackColor];
  set1.lineWidth = 2.0;
  set1.circleRadius = 3.0;
  set1.drawCircleHoleEnabled = YES;
  set1.valueFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.f];
  set1.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor;
  
  NSArray *gradientColors = @[
                              (id)[ChartColorTemplates colorFromString:@"#0000ff00"].CGColor,
                              (id)[ChartColorTemplates colorFromString:@"#ffff0000"].CGColor
                              ];
  CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(nil, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors, nil);
  
  set1.fillAlpha = 1.f;
  set1.fill = [ChartFill fillWithLinearGradient:gradient angle:90.f];
  set1.drawFilledEnabled = YES;
  
  NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [dataSets addObject:set1];
  
  LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets];
  
  _chartView.data = data;
}


#pragma mark - ChartViewDelegate

- (void)chartValueSelected:(ChartViewBase * __nonnull)chartView entry:(ChartDataEntry * __nonnull)entry dataSetIndex:(NSInteger)dataSetIndex highlight:(ChartHighlight * __nonnull)highlight
{ }

- (void)chartValueNothingSelected:(ChartViewBase * __nonnull)chartView
{ }

@end
```

### js side

**CustomCharts.js**

```
import React from 'react-native';
var { requireNativeComponent } = React;
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('CustomCharts', null);
```

**index.ios.js**

```
import CustomCharts from './CustomCharts';

// some other code

return (
  <CustomCharts style={{ flex: 1, }} /> 
)
```

I have no idea now :(

could anybody help me?

thanks for your time.

regards.

Comment: Looks fine to me :) But seriously -- it looks like a lot of what you're doing in `CustomChartsManager.m` could be resolved with https://github.com/Jpadilla1/react-native-ios-charts.

Comment: @HaL thank you!  it's what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your view is `opaque=true` and `backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()`.

If your view is opaque you must supply an opaque color. Otherwise- set it to `opaque=true`.